# Terraform: how to access S3 bucket object from EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have an archive that contains some binary on S3 which I need to put on EC2 during the provisioning.
On the moment, I am downloading the archive to the machine(host provisioned) and upload it to the machine which I need to provision.

Or how can I get a link from
aws_s3_bucket_object? or is there a way to mount s3 object as file into ec2 instance with terraform?

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "release" {
  bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.artifacts.id
  key    = "release.tgz"
}

resource "aws_instance" "engine" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.server.id
  instance_type = var.aws_instance_type
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't mount S3 objects** as a filesystem to your instance, nor access them directly. They have to be downloaded first.

However, you can use **third part tool** which make S3 bucket appear to you and your application as a filesystem. One popular tool for that is [3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) which :

> allows Linux and macOS to **mount an S3 bucket** via FUSE. s3fs preserves the native object format for files, allowing use of other tools like AWS CLI.

For that to work you would have to setup your [user_data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data) in your instance to do it **automatically** during the instance launch.